# Uploading jpeg to Google Drive from Android app "unexpected end of stream"

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've built an Android application where I use the camera to take a photo, and then attempt to upload the photo to my Google Drive account. Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
    b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
            driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
            driveRequest.setKey(MY_CLIENT_ID);
            driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
        }
    });

    final Drive drive = b.build();


    final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
    body.setTitle(mCurrentPhotoPath.substring(mCurrentPhotoPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, mCurrentPhotoPath.length()));
    body.setDescription("A Test File");
    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", file);
    //final InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", new FileInputStream(file));

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

                System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
                System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
            }
            catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();

                System.err.println("Error code:" + error.getCode());
                System.err.println("Error message: " + error.getMessage());

                // More error information can be retrieved with error.getErrors().
            }
            catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // No Json body was returned by the API.
                System.err.println("HTTP Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
                System.err.println("HTTP Reason: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // Other errors (e.g connection timeout, etc.).
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

What's happening is that I'm getting the following exceptions in logcat:

```
09-17 22:11:31.683: WARN/HttpTransport(11701): exception thrown while executing request
    java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
    at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.close(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:58)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:991)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:279)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:309)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
    at com.xxxxxx.UploadImageService$2.run(UploadImageService.java:143)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

When I stepped through the Google Drive and Client code to see what it was doing, it actually seemed to work twice. But now it's failing again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured out my issue. It's strange the error I was getting from the drive api, but ultimately, I think I was trying to capture images from the camera and save them with only a timestamp up to the second. I added milliseconds in the filename and so far I haven't seen the exception again. We'll see.