# Google Drive + Android: unexpected end of stream when uploading big files

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an Android application which upload a zipped backup of your files in the Cloud.

Until recently I was using exclusively Dropbox and it was working very well.

Recently I decided to implement the support for Google Drive.

When the file is small (approx 15Mb), it is working... most of the time (sometimes I get a 401 error after the upload has started).

When the file is big (>1Gb), I always get the error :

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
```

Here is my code:

```
public CloudResult sendFile(File fileContent, long added) {
    CloudResult result = new CloudResult();

    try {

        mProgress = new FileUploadProgressListener(fileContent.getName());
        mediaContent = new FileContent(ZIP_MIME_TYPE, fileContent);

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
        body.setMimeType(ZIP_MIME_TYPE);

        Drive.Files.Insert inserted = getDrive().files().insert(body, mediaContent);
        inserted.getMediaHttpUploader()
                .setDirectUploadEnabled(false)
                .setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE)
                .setProgressListener(mProgress);

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f = inserted.execute();

        // loop over all files in drive and see if any need to be
        // synced locally
        FileList driveFilesList = getDrive().files().list().execute();

        mTotalUploaded = added;
        for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File remote : driveFilesList.getItems()) {
            Log.d(Ln.TAG, remote.getLabels().toPrettyString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = new CloudResult(getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        if (Ln.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(Ln.TAG, "Error in GDrive - " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As I don't have real controlon the InputStream, I don't know what to do.

I have already some waker on during the process.

Everything is executed in a thread inside a Service. The Service is the same than for Dropbox, so the error is not about the way this code is executed. It is somewhere else, but I don't know where! May be a bug with GDrive.

I have found these threads, but there is no real answer:
[Uploading jpeg to Google Drive from Android app "unexpected end of stream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469588/uploading-jpeg-to-google-drive-from-android-app-unexpected-end-of-stream)

Any ideas?

**Second question:** how to get a linear progress listener and not something which is called after each chunck is uploaded (here every 10Mb)?